# Month wise display data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have small question about SQL Server.

I have a table with sample data like this:

```
id | month  | stat   | count
---------------------------------
1  |     1  | admit  |  7
2  |     8  | admit  | 47
1  |     7  | admit  | 28
2  |     9  | admit  | 11
3  |    12  | dischr |  4
4  |    10  | openc  |  5
1  |    11  | admit  |  1
2  |     6  | admit  |  5
2  |     4  | admit  |  8
1  |     3  | dischr | 10
2  |     2  | admit  | 30
3  |     5  | dischr | 20
1  |     8  | admit  | 13
3  |     8  | dischr |  1
4  |     9  | admit  | 30
2  |    10  | admit  | 20
3  |    10  | deschr | 20
```

Based on this when month=1 then January and when month=2 then February all the way through 12, based on that condition I got output like below.

```
Month   |id |Admit  |Dischr |OpenC
August  |1  |13 |NULL   |NULL
January |1  |7  |NULL   |NULL
July    |1  |28 |NULL   |NULL
March   |1  |NULL   |10 |NULL
November|1  |1  |NULL   |NULL
April   |2  |8  |NULL   |NULL
August  |2  |47 |NULL   |NULL
February|2  |30 |NULL   |NULL
June    |2  |5  |NULL   |NULL
October 2   |20 |NULL   |NULL
September|2 |11 |NULL   |NULL
August  |3  |NULL   |1  |NULL
December|3  |NULL   |4  |NULL
May     |3  |NULL   |20 |NULL
October |3  |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
October |4  |NULL   |NULL   |5
September|4 |30 |NULL   |NULL
```

but I want output like month wise proper order and output look like below

```
Month   |id |Admit  |Dischr |OpenC
January |1  |7  |NULL   |NULL
February|2  |30 |NULL   |NULL
March   |1  |NULL   |10 |NULL
April   |2  |8  |NULL   |NULL
May     |3  |NULL   |20 |NULL
June    |2  |5  |NULL   |NULL
July    |1  |28 |NULL   |NULL
August  |1  |13 |NULL   |NULL
August  |2  |47 |NULL   |NULL
August  |3  |NULL   |1  |NULL
September|2 |11 |NULL   |NULL
September|4 |30 |NULL   |NULL
October |2  |20 |NULL   |NULL
October |3  |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
October |4  |NULL   |NULL   |5
November|1  |1  |NULL   |NULL
December|3  |NULL   |4  |NULL
```

Please tell me query how to solve this issue in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `convert` the `month` column to `date` and use it in `order by` with `ID`

```
SELECT [Month],
        id,
        Admit,
        Dischr,
        OpenC
FROM   yourTable
ORDER  BY Cast([Month] + '01 2010' AS DATE),Id
```

or

```
order by DATEPART(MM,[Month]+ ' 01 2010'),Id
```

**Note :** `'1 2010'` in cast is just a static value to `convert` the `month` varchar column to `date`

Comment: This should be the exact answer what you are looking for @user3457912

Answer (score 0):

Add `order by` clause to your query to ensure your data is ordered according to your requirement. Something like this

```
SELECT ....
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Month, Id
```